# why jquery selector regx string /^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/ match result include 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var rquickExpr = /^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/;
var str = ' <div id=top></div>';
var match = rquickExpr.exec(str);
console.log(match);
```

then i get

```
[" <div id=top></div>", "<div id=top></div>", undefined, index: 0, input: " <div id=top></div>"]
```

why there is undefined?

Comment: The second group did not match. You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7lH7/1) (when enabling the SHOW NON-PARTICIAPTING GROUPS in the *Options*). What is that you really need? Is the regex working as expected or not? Before using the match results, just check `if (m[2])` and then use it.

Comment: It's not a *jQuery* regex. It's a *JavaScript* regex. jQuery is a library of DOM manipulation functions, not a language, and has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: And...[obligatory link about trying to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454).